# Error:Data Binding does not support Jack builds yet

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-jack-and-jill

I am implementing `DataBinding`, it is working perfect, but it is not allowing me to use `jackOptions`. It throws error `Data Binding does not support Jack builds yet` while build.

Here is my `build.gradle`

```
android {


   defaultConfig {
       ...

       dataBinding {
           enabled true
       }

       jackOptions {
           enabled true
       }
   }

   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
}
```

Comment: It seems like: *Data Binding does not support Jack builds **yet***

Comment: @Selvin might be, i just want to confirm whether am i doing anything wrong or not.

Comment: we are working on it...

Comment: @RRR can you check if your disable `jackOptions { enabled flase }` it work.

Comment: I can confirm, on my Android Studio 2.2 Beta install it doesnt work yet with DataBinding also

Comment: Seems like it wont be in AS 2.2 at all https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210615

Answer (score 9):

From yigit's comment it's clear that this functionality is still under development as he and George are project member of DataBinding.

> we are working on it... [yigit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303415/errordata-binding-does-not-support-jack-builds-yet?noredirect=1#comment64169315_38303415)

I have also found that issue is already reported [Issue 210615: Databinding with Jack compiler](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210615)

**UPDATE**

[2.3 will allow you to use data binding with jack but it still has limitations](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210615#c13)

Comment: Hmmm... still doesn't work.  Is it expected to be release-ready?

Answer (score 2):

> Google will add support for Java 8 language features directly into the
>   current javac and dx set of tools, and deprecate the Jack toolchain.

Check this out , Future of Java 8 Language Feature Support on Android

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html

**Updates**:

Java 8 language features are now supported by the Android build system

> Yesterday, we released Android Studio 2.4 Preview 6. Java 8 language
>   features are now supported by the Android build system in the javac/dx
>   compilation path. Android Studio's Gradle plugin now desugars Java 8
>   class files to Java 7-compatible class files, so you can use lambdas,
>   method references and other features of Java 8.

Source : https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/java-8-language-features-support-update.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this is very useful.

Comment: Ok, but preview Android Studio builds are too risky for use for production projects. We need to wait for 2.4 stable. BTW Jack is sometimes extremely slow, compilation takes ages

Answer (score 0):

As of gradle:2.2.0-alpha5, Jack builds are not yet compatible with DataBinding.

If you want to use data binding with Java 8, you can use [retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda).

Comment: retrolambda doesn't do data binding does it? I never used it but it definitely seems out of scope for a lambda support library.

Comment: Retrolambda has nothing to do with databinding.

Comment: Though unrelated, Retrolambda IS compatible with databinding.

Comment: That wouldn't be Java 8, just a Java 8 simulated feature (and those lambdas are costlier in performance)