# Data Binding with JDK 8

Tags: android, android-databinding

As I saw the replies from the question([Error:Data Binding does not support Jack builds yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303415/errordata-binding-does-not-support-jack-builds-yet)), the data binding is not yet support the JDK8 ( since it required JACK enabled in AS).

However, I saw the data binding usage from the official using the lambdas expression.
(https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#listener_bindings)

Is there any way I can use data binding with JDK 8 since I started to test the App with databinding with API 24(required JDK 8)???

```
 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:onClick="@{() -> presenter.onSaveClick(task)}" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you need data binding for that? Can't you just do `android:onClick="onSaveClick"`?

Comment: I started to develop the app with API 23 using the data binding with this syntax. Now I want to migrate the current code using lambdas expression( A lot of Rx in my app) , but it does not work ( u know, data binding is not supported to JACK yet)

Comment: It's not entirely clear that the lambdas in the databinding require the Jack compiler. It only says that Gradle 1.5.0-alpha1 or higher is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is no support for Jack Build yet, but you can use lambda expressions in XMl files.

As the update from yigit https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210615#c11

> These issues do not affect all apps and are not specific to data
>   binding (any annotation processor can hit them). We'll release an
>   experimental integration in 2.3 and also working on fixing those
>   issues.

Still if you want to use lambda with Data Binding, you can use it. But if you want other features in java, you cannot.